# Opening a picker in Android client app without downloading OneDrive aap

Tags: android, onedrive

From inside my client app, I want to access OneDrive files and folders. The way I am designing it is, that initially the use can press a button to login into his onedrive account (app redirects to web for login and then redirects back to app).

After this, I want to show a chooser box with all files and folders for that user and clicking on anyone of the files, it should open up in my app (Right now I want it to work for images).

From my app, login works fine now but I cannot find a way to show all files and folders inside my app without downloading OneDrive App.

As my app is for Android Tv, so OneDrive app is not available for download on TV.

Thanks for any help

Based on Dominik4142 advice, I implemented and getting following json reply:

This is the URL I am sending:

> "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?pretty=false&access_token=xyz"

{"data":[{"id":"folder.d01bec024f17580d.D01BEC024F17580D!106","from":{"name":"xxxx belgium","id":"d01bec024f17580d"},"name":"Documents","description":"","parent_id":"folder.d01bec024f17580d","size":0,"upload_location":"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.d01bec024f17580d.D01BEC024F17580D!106/files/","comments_count":0,"comments_enabled":false,"is_embeddable":true,"count":0,"link":"https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=d01bec024f17580d&page=browse&resid=D01BEC024F17580D!106&parId=D01BEC024F17580D!103","type":"folder","shared_with":{"access":"Just me"},"created_time":"2014-05-27T11:38:30+0000","updated_time":"2014-05-27T11:38:30+0000","client_updated_time":"2014-05-27T11:38:30+0000"},{"id":"folder.d01bec024f17580d.D01BEC024F17580D!104","from":{"name":"xxxx belgium","id":"d01bec024f17580d"},"name":"Pictures","description":"","parent_id":"folder.d01bec024f17580d","size":1279592,"upload_location":"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.d01bec024f17580d.D01BEC024F17580D!104/files/","comments_count":0,"comments_enabled":false,"is_embeddable":true,"count":1,"link":"https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=d01bec024f17580d&page=browse&resid=D01BEC024F17580D!104&parId=D01BEC024F17580D!103","type":"album","shared_with":{"access":"Just me"},"created_time":"2014-05-27T11:38:29+0000","updated_time":"2014-05-27T11:39:00+0000","client_updated_time":"2014-05-27T11:38:29+0000"},{"id":"folder.d01bec024f17580d.D01BEC024F17580D!105","from":{"name":"xxxx belgium","id":"d01bec024f17580d"},"name":"Public","description":"","parent_id":"folder.d01bec024f17580d","size":16775184,"upload_location":"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.d01bec024f17580d.D01BEC024F17580D!105/files/","comments_count":0,"comments_enabled":true,"is_embeddable":true,"count":2,"link":"https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=d01bec024f17580d&page=browse&resid=D01BEC024F17580D!105&parId=D01BEC024F17580D!103","type":"folder","shared_with":{"access":"Public"},"created_time":"2014-05-27T11:38:29+0000","updated_time":"2014-05-27T11:42:06+0000","client_updated_time":"2014-05-27T11:38:29+0000"},{"id":"folder.d01bec024f17580d.D01BEC024F17580D!112","from":{"name":"xxxx belgium","id":"d01bec024f17580d"},"name":"sushil","description":"","parent_id":"folder.d01bec024f17580d","size":212738,"upload_location":"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.d01bec024f17580d.D01BEC024F17580D!112/files/","comments_count":0,"comments_enabled":false,"is_embeddable":true,"count":1,"link":"https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=d01bec024f17580d&page=browse&resid=D01BEC024F17580D!112&parId=D01BEC024F17580D!103","type":"album","shared_with":{"access":"Just me"},"created_time":"2014-10-16T15:04:21+0000","updated_time":"2014-10-16T15:05:21+0000","client_updated_time":"2014-10-16T15:05:21+0000"}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use OneDrive API for Android. Exact link for downloading file list in external android apps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659727.aspx

Comment: I saw this link but then it for downloading for a particular URL which I need to feed. How would I know the urls? Also, I want to list of the folders(nested floders and files) initially from which user can choose from..

Comment: All these methods are just helpers for restful calls. I would try to start with what is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631844.aspx (call to path 'albums' https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/albums?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN exactly)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to look into it.

Comment: Using what you suggested, I can get some json back and probably can build my solution on top of it. So, I will accept your answer as correct answer. If possible can you guide me with some code to list all folders and as listview and can be clicked to get nested folder/files.

Comment: Do you get information about folder names you want to show? It would be great if you attached simple onedrive json response. Having this, I think opening folder wont be that difficult.

Comment: @TheCommonGuy I dont know if you got previous reply but Im willing to extend previous answer to some code and real use scenario. I would only need json object that you currently get :)

Comment: Thanks for extending your helping hand. I have edited my answer to add my json output.

Comment: Ok, in that case you will need to fetch list of objects with fields: String id, name, description, parent_id, upload_location, link, type, created_time, updated_time, client_updated_time; Integer size, comments_count, count; boolean comments_enabled, is_embeddable; and a few other complex objects. You need to show 'name' strings on the list. How - up to you. Possibly by going through list and creating list that will contain only this strings?